# Problems with arrays and divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The header isn't displaying any image when I use this code and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, this is just the code thats giving me trouble I'm not missing anything above or below it.

```
<script>
  var image = new Array ();
  image[0] = "header1.png";
  image[1] = "header2.png";
  image[2] = "header3.png";
  image[3] = "header4.png";
  var size = image.length
  var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())
  $('#random').attr('src',image[x]);
</script>
<div class="header-img background-cover"  style="background-image: url('random');">
```

Answer (score 7):

Your problems:

- The script is running before the target div has been rendered, so it has nothing to render into - try putting the script tag after the div.
- You're not targeting the div properly - you're doing $("#random") which selects an element with an id of "random", and that doesn't exist
- The background image is trying to resolve the url "random", which won't resolve.

A better approach is to set the "background-image" style property directly. Something like this:

```
<div id="header-image" class="header-img background-cover">
<script>
  // this now executes after the div has rendered
  var image = new Array ();
  image[0] = "header1.png";
  image[1] = "header2.png";
  image[2] = "header3.png";
  image[3] = "header4.png";
  var size = image.length
  var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())
  var backgroundImageFile = image[x];   // 'header1.png'
  var backgroundImageUrl = "url('" + backgroundImageFile + "')";   // url('header1.png')
  $('#header-image').css('background-image', backgroundImageUrl);
</script>
```

Comment: It seems as if the OP may have assumed that `background-image: url('random')` would literally set the background of the div to match an img element with the ID "random" (which might or might not actually exist elsewhere on their page). Of course it doesn't work that way, but it's kind of an understandable mistake to make if one doesn't really understand what `url(...)` does in CSS.